# Не могу в двумерном массиве вывести нужную информацию

Tags: c, массивы

Нужно найти число пар одинаковых соседних элементов в строках массива, но выводится вообще не то. Не понимаю, где ошибка.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define n 5
int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int a[n][n];
int i, j, p, sum;
sum=0;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
a[i][j]=rand()%10;
//printf("\nMassiv:%d%d", a[i][j]);
}

}
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
for (j=1;j<=(n-1);j++){;
p=a[i, j+1];
if (p=a[i, j]){
sum=(sum + 1);
}
}
printf("String=%d\nElements=%d\n", i, sum);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что это вы к элементам массива обращаетесь то как `a[i][j]`, то как `a[i, j]`? Вас ничего не смущает?

Comment: Эта ошибка ни на что не влияла. Исправил, результат тот же((

Comment: Компилятор С++ просто не скомпилировал бы ваш код. С выдает предупреждения: "t.c(20): warning C4709: запятая-оператор в выражении индекса массива
t.c(20): warning C4047: =: "int" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "int *"
t.c(21): warning C4709: запятая-оператор в выражении индекса массива
t.c(21): warning C4047: =: "int" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "int *"
t.c(25): warning C4013: printf: нет определения; предполагается "extern" с возвратом типа "int"
G:\Tmp\Test\t.c(21) : warning C4706: назначение в пределах условного выражения" — не хотите их исправить?